# sorting an array of objects by datetime variable

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, symfony, datetime

I want to sort an array of object by their datetime variable, the dates are situated in the future and I want to date thats closest to the current date as the first one.

I'm using following controlleraction in symfony2:

```
public function fixturesAction(){
        if (false === $this->get('security.context')->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')) {
            throw $this->createAccessDeniedException('Unable to access this page!');
        }

        $user = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
        $team = $this->getDoctrine()
                ->getRepository('LoginLoginBundle:Team')
                ->findByUserUserid($user->getUserid());
        $matchGamesHome = $this->getDoctrine()
                        ->getRepository('LoginLoginBundle:Matchgame')
                        ->findByHometeam($team[0]->getName());
        $matchGamesAway = $this->getDoctrine()
                        ->getRepository('LoginLoginBundle:Matchgame')
                        ->findByAwayteam($team[0]->getName());

        $matchGames = array_merge($matchGamesHome, $matchGamesAway);

        $sorted = usort($matchGames, function($a, $b) {
            return $a->date->format('U') - $b->date->format('U');
        });

        return $this->render('LoginLoginBundle:Default:fixtures.html.twig', array("matchArray"=>$sorted));
    }
```

Where I do the sorting:

```
$sorted = usort($matchGames, function($a, $b) {
                return $a->date->format('U') - $b->date->format('U');
            });
```

This yields me the following error:

```
Error: Cannot access private property Login\LoginBundle\Entity\Matchgame::$date in C:\wamp\www\SocProNetbeans\src\Login\LoginBundle\Controller\DefaultController.php line 675
```

Line 675 is the following:

```
return $a->date->format('U') - $b->date->format('U');
```

What is the proper way to sort this array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I don't know which line the error speaks of, this is a small shot in the dark:

Replace

```
return $a['date']->format('U') - $b['date']->format('U');
```

with

```
return $a->date->format('U') - $b->date->format('U');
```

Comment: I have replaced it but now I get a different error, I edited the OP

Comment: The error is pretty self-explanatory... The `date` property is private in the used class/object... You can set it to `public` or see if there is a 'getter' like `getDate()` for this property

Comment: yeah thought of it already, but now when I do var_dump($sorted) I just get 'boolean true' ...

Comment: @HardUser That's right... $matchGames is sorted, the returnvalue of `usort()` is true on success... See http://php.net/usort

Comment: I see, I understand everything now and everything works, thanks! :p

Answer (score 0):

1. Your DB schema seems to be bad. `LoginLoginBundle:Matchgame` has two properties `hometeam` and `awayteam` which store the *names* of the associated teams. Why not the **IDs**? This is a [OneToMany/ManyToOne association](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-bidirectional) which should be managed by doctrine.
2. `->findByUserUserid` you want to get one row. So it should be `->findOneByUserUserid` (But why user_userid??)
3. Databases are heavily optimized for sorting. Let the DB do the job.
4. You can write pretty complex DQL queries. Write a custom table repository for your methods.

This query should do what you want, but again: Improve the database schema first!

```
$query = $em->createQuery('
    SELECT g
    FROM LoginLoginBundle:Matchgame g
    WHERE g.hometeam = :hometeam
       OR g.awayteam = :awayteam
    ORDER BY g.date ASC
');
$query->setParameter('hometeam', $team);
$query->setParameter('awayteam', $team);
$matches = $query->getResult();
```

Comment: Hey, yeah I thought already my schema wasn't to perfect, however this is a learning project for me personal and databases aren't really my strong suit. I will try to update the schema as you said but this is the first time I'm working with mysql so it will be a pain :p